# facebook login on android with titanium

Tags: android, facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I had a titanium (appcelerator) app with the facebook login working.

I recently re open my IDE (appcelerator studio), do the updates, then relauch the app in an emulator, and the facebook login does't work anymore..

The error is:

```
Log in attempt failed: FacebookActivity could not be started. Please make sure you added FacebookActivity to the AndroidManifest.
```

The documentation is the same. There is my tiapp.xml (android node):

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.0.5">
        <application android:theme="@style/LightDarkBar">
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

part of login.js (the controller)

```
function fbLogin() {
    $.btn_fb.opacity=0.5;

    facebook.addEventListener('login', onFbLogin);

    facebook.permissions = ['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'];
    facebook.authorize();
}


$.login.fbProxy = facebook.createActivityWorker({lifecycleContainer: $.login});

$.login.open();
```

And obviously there is a Button onSingletap="fbLogin" in the view.

I use `<sdk-version>5.2.0.GA</sdk-version>` in tiapp.xml.

The documentation here http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook is not helping.

Anyone please ?

Comment: Did you also follow the "Add the Facebook App ID to Android Resources" section in http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook to set the value of `facebook_app_id`?

Comment: Yep, the solution was to rename the activity, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

The name of that activity isn't FacebookActivity, so the login will not work, into the official changelog of Titanium 5.2 you can see a reference to [this](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19577) ticket.

Comment: Thanks, I've reported this documentation bug here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-2204

Answer (score 1):

Here is my manifest that I used to successfully apply the log in feature of Facebook Module.

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application>
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

And here is the content in the file "Platform/android/res/values/strings.xml"

```
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">my_facebook_ap_id</string>
</resources
```